# How to integrate sitemaps to django-oscar?

Tags: python, django, robots.txt, django-oscar, django-sitemaps

I want to integrate sitemaps for my oscar project and I used [django-sitemaps](https://pypi.org/project/django-sitemaps/) package
I followed the same, created an app called sitemaps-django, configured views.py, sitemaps-django/pages/sitemaps.py, URLconf in main urls.py file

**Views.py**

```
from sitemaps_django.pages.sitemaps import PagesSitemap

def sitemap(request):
    sitemap = Sitemap(
        build_absolute_uri=request.build_absolute_uri,
    )

    # URLs can be added one-by-one. The only required argument
    # is the URL. All other arguments are keyword-only arguments.
    for p in Page.objects.active():
        url = p.get_absolute_url()
        sitemap.add(
            url,
            changefreq='weekly',
            priority=0.5,
            lastmod=p.modification_date,
            alternates={
                code: urljoin(domain, url)
                for code, domain in PAGE_DOMAINS[p.language].items()
            },
        )

    # Adding conventional Django sitemaps is supported. The
    # request argument is necessary because Django's sitemaps
    # depend on django.contrib.sites, resp. RequestSite.
    sitemap.add_django_sitemap(PagesSitemap, request=request)

    # You could get the serialized XML...
    # ... = sitemap.serialize([pretty_print=False])
    # ... or use the ``response`` helper to return a
    # ready-made ``HttpResponse``:
    return sitemap.response(
        # pretty_print is False by default
        pretty_print=settings.DEBUG,
    )
```

**sitemaps-django/pages/sitemaps.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', robots_txt(
        timeout=86400,
        sitemaps=[
            '/sitemap.xml',
            reverse_lazy('articles-sitemap'),
            ...,
        ],
    )),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django_sitemaps import robots_txt
from sitemaps_django.views import sitemap

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap),
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', robots_txt(timeout=86400)),
    ...
]
```

### I get this error

```
url(r'^robots\.txt$', robots_txt(
NameError: name 'robots_txt' is not defined
```

Comment: You probably forgot to import robots_txt in sitemaps.py

Comment: Thank you I've included the import robots_txt in sitemaps.py and the above error is solved

Comment: An error again stats 'cannot import name 'PagesSitemap'' and even in the documentation there is no class called PagesSitemap in sitemaps.py, Please help me out

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. If `PagesSitemap` does not exist and isn't mentioned in the documentation, then where are you getting it from?